# Error: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. although network input is 2d (lstm)

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm, tf.keras

I have the network to classify sequences:

```
input_shape = (500, )
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=conv_filters, kernel_size=conv_kernel_size,
                 padding='valid', activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=conv_filters, kernel_size=conv_kernel_size,
                 padding='valid', activation='relu'))
model.add(LSTM(units=lstm_units, dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.1))
model.add(Dense(n_classes, activation="softmax"))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And I am trying to run:

```
model.fit(X,y)
```

When shape of X is `<1200, 500 >` and of y is `<12000>`
I get the error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv1d is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 500)
```

But I am not sure why as it should only be 2d.
What do I get wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: your input must be 3d: (samples, timesteps, features)

Comment: @MarcoCerliani But where is the NN is timesteps defined/used? So if I want my timesteps to be 100 what is the best way to change the NN and transform the array accordingly?

Comment: you have to reshape your data accordingly and then set input_shape=(timestep,features) in your first conv layer

Comment: @MarcoCerliani So assuming 1 have 1d then X should be with the shape of (5, 100, 1) instead of (500, 1) and input_shape = (100, 1)?

Comment: if 5 is yours n_samples and 100 are timesteps and 1 are n_features, yes

Comment: @MarcoCerliani Oh so I didn't understand. I have 1200 samples with 500 features. So now my new array shape now should be (120000, 5,500)?